# Decimal Module in Python

Tags: python, decimal

Why does this code output `25` although I used the decimal module. I tried it on the calculator and it outputted `26.28`.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2

targetPrice = 40
currentPrice = 56.5
winChance = 0.9
stopLoss = 23
lossChance = 0.1

expectancy =100 * abs(((Decimal(targetPrice) -  Decimal(currentPrice)) / Decimal( currentPrice))) *  Decimal(winChance)
print(expectancy)
```

Comment: You are doing all of your calculations with a precision of 2. This introduces a fair amount of round-off error. Your calculator uses more like 15 decimal places of precision. Not surprisingly, it is more accurate. The decimal module is intended for calculations which are higher precision than a 64-bit float. For some reason you are using it for lower-precision calculations.

Comment: Applying `Decimal()` to floating-point values entirely misses the point of the Decimal module.  0.9, for example, is not a value that can be accurately represented as a float; turning it into a Decimal results in a precise value that isn't quite equal to 0.9.  You have to use strings - `Decimal('0.9')` for example - to produce exact values.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting inexact results because you're rounding down to two decimal places after every calculation.  Your calculator isn't doing that.

With no rounding.

```
>>> (Decimal(40) - Decimal(56.5)) / Decimal(56.5)
Decimal('-0.2920353982300884955752212389')
```

With rounding:

```
>>> (Decimal(40) - Decimal(56.5)) / Decimal(56.5)
Decimal('-0.28')
```

It only gets worse after that.

Comment: Should we use strings as suggested in @jasonharper's comment under OP?